# Problem with list processing in Flask with Jinja2 templates

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Having a bit of a logic issue with Jinja2, what I'm trying to do is enable items in the menu based on their name and whether there is a session active., however the "Admin and account items show up in all circumstances. The interesting thing is that they match on the second case if there is a session and the third case if there isn't but the way I'm looking at it the third case should exclude them altogether. Another set of eyes would be very helpful.

```
                    {% if headerinf.nav %}
                        {% for item in headerinf.nav %}
                            {% if item.tag == "Home" %}
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="{{ item.url }}">*{{ item.tag }}</a>
                            </li>
                            {% else %}
                                {% if (item.tag == "Account" or item.tag == "Admin") and session %}
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ item.url }}">#{{ item.tag }}</a>
                                </li>
                                {% elif (item.tag != "Account" or item.tag != "Admin")%}
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ item.url }}">&{{ item.tag }}</a>
                                </li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href=" ">Nav list missing</a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `item.tag != "Account" or item.tag != "Admin` always evalutates to true because `item.tag` is one ("True or False") or the other ("False or True") or neither("True or True"). If you want the menu item when it is neither, the `or` needs to be an `and`. If you want the menu item when it is one or the other, the `!=` needs to be `=`.